# Inject record into a Journey with HTTPPost interaction/v1/events from an an SMS message send

Tags: marketing-cloud

I am looking to pull the Auth token then use it to inject a record into an active Event Entry Journey. When I run the full code in Cloudpages, I get a record injected to the expected Journey. When I then put the code into a SMS Message, SFMC is unable to send the SMS through. Am I doing something wrong here? Do you have any idea if this is possible?

**Other information:**

- The DE linked to the journey has all the fields in the @journeyBody
  variable, all fields are NOT NULLABLE.
- Date fields are date data type, Mobile is phone data type while the
  rest are Text.
- I have sent an SMS to myself with the Auth httpost section and
  managed to correctly generate the token which makes me think the
  httpost part for injecting a record in a journey can't be done

**Here is my code:**

```
%%[ 
SET @Contact_Key = _SubscriberKey
SET @MobilePhone = AttributeValue("MobilePhone")
SET @FirstName = AttributeValue("FirstName")
SET @AppointmentDate = AttributeValue("AppointmentDate")
SET @AppDateFormat = FORMATDATE(@AppointmentDate,"MMMM dd, yyyy h:mm")
SET @Case_ID = AttributeValue("Case_ID")
SET @Message_Assessment = "SFMC_Y"
SET @Inbound_or_Outbound = "Outbound"
SET @DateAddedAEST = Format(SystemDateToLocalDate(Now()),"yyyy/MM/dd h:mm:ss.tt")
SET @MessageText = Concat("[SFMC] Hi ",@FirstName,", please confirm you are free for your appointment on the following date: ",@AppDateFormat,". Reply to this SMS with a Yes or a No.")
SET  @body = '{"client_id": "EEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEEE","client_secret": "QQQQQQQQQQQQQQQQ", "grant_type": "client_credentials"}'
SET  @accessToken = HTTPPost2("https://RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR.auth.marketingcloudapis.com/v2/token", "application/json", @body, True, @callstatus, @response)
SET @PullaccessToken = REGEXMATCH(@callstatus,'^(?:.*"access_token":")(.*?)(?:".*)$',1)
SET @journeyBody = '{
    "ContactKey": @Contact_Key,
    "EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS",
    "EstablishContactKey": true,
    "Data": { "Contact_Key": @Contact_Key, 
              "MobilePhone": @MobilePhone, 
              "FirstName":@FirstName, 
              "AppointmentDate": @AppointmentDate, 
              "Case_ID": @Case_ID, 
              "MessageText": @MessageText, 
              "Message_Assessment": @Message_Assessment, 
              "Inbound_or_Outbound": @Inbound_or_Outbound, 
              "DateAddedAEST": @DateAddedAEST
            }
   }'
SET @bearerAccess_token = CONCAT('Bearer ', @PullaccessToken)

HTTPPost2("https://RRRRRRRRRRRRRRRRR.rest.marketingcloudapis.com/interaction/v1/events", 'application/json', @journeyBody, True, @output,@respheader, 'Authorization', @bearerAccess_token)
]%%


%%=v(@MessageText)=%%
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you have two issues here:

**1) You are not sending values, just variable names**

Your whole `@journeyBody` is a string and the variables there are not replaced by their values. You are literally sending this:

```
{
"ContactKey": @Contact_Key,
"EventDefinitionKey": "APIEvent-SSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSSS",
"EstablishContactKey": true,
"Data": { "Contact_Key": @Contact_Key, 
            "MobilePhone": @MobilePhone, 10
            "FirstName":@FirstName, 
            "AppointmentDate": @AppointmentDate, 
            "Case_ID": @Case_ID, 
            "MessageText": @MessageText, 
            "Message_Assessment": @Message_Assessment, 
            "Inbound_or_Outbound": @Inbound_or_Outbound, 
            "DateAddedAEST": @DateAddedAEST
        }
}
```

You need to modify the code and build the `@journeyBody` using the `Concat()` function or by using `Replace()` to put the values in place of the stringified variable names.

The second way is lazy, but requires to just add this to your code after setting the `@journeyBody`:

```
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@Contact_Key', @Contact_Key) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@MobilePhone', @MobilePhone) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@FirstName', @FirstName) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@AppointmentDate', @AppointmentDate) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@Case_ID', @Case_ID) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@MessageText', @MessageText) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@Message_Assessment', @Message_Assessment) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@Inbound_or_Outbound', @Inbound_or_Outbound) 
SET @journeyBody = Replace(@journeyBody, '@DateAddedAE', @DateAddedAE)
```

**2) Strings need to be enclosed**

In a proper JSON body, strings are enclosed with either single or double quotes. For example, if you go with the Replace method of building the JSON, strings would need to look like this:

```
`"ContactKey": "@Contact_Key",
(...)
"FirstName": "@FirstName",
```

Comment: Thanks Rafal! You are an absolute legend! I am still getting use to AMPscript, I prefer using SSJS :P

Take care mate